# Excel Match function as array formula serching multiple colums

Tags: excel, function, match

I've got some problem with this function. I've Tried to find position some cell on the list consisted of two columns. My formula MATCH(A1;D1:E10;0) gives me an #N/D error, but when I change formula for each separate column like e.g. MATCH(A1;D1:D10;0) it works. Is three possibility to do this simultanously for both colums. Maybe some array formula?

Answer (score 1):

Match will not work with 2 dimensional ranges.

You can use AGGREGATE to return the correct ROW:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(D1:E10)/(D1:E10 = A1),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Then you do not have any cells in `D1:E10` that equal `A1`  check to ensure that there is a match and that match does not have extra spaces or other characters.

Comment: I've put in all cells in D1:E10 the same value from A1 but nothing's changed, the same error

Comment: @AnonimowyAnonim See edit, for proof of it working.  `#NUM` error means that the value is not found in the range.